# How to send logs to multiple outputs with same match tags in Fluentd?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, amazon-s3, fluentd

I have a Fluentd instance, and I need it to send my logs matching the `fv-back-*` tags to Elasticsearch and Amazon S3.

Is there a way to configure Fluentd to send data to both of these outputs? Right now I can only send logs to one source using the `<match fv-back-*>` config directive.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible using the `@type copy` directive.

Docs: https://docs.fluentd.org/output/copy